# How can I generate a random timestamp appended to getdate() in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following sql select generates the current date and time:

```
select
Getdate() AS DueDate
```

which looks like:

```
2021-02-06 10:16:35.340
```

I'd like to use getdate() (or an equivalent alternative) to continue getting the current date but I'd like to randomize the time component. I am having trouble finding a workable solution within a select statement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do we assume you mean you want a *different* random time component for each row, or the *same* random time component for each row?

Comment: different random time for each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is another way if you need to have random time for each row:

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(SECOND ,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 86400,CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),112))) 
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add another `DATEADD` around your expression. For example, using INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MILLISECOND, RAND(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION)) * 10000000, GETDATE())
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
```

You can play around with the `RAND()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` functions to get the result you want. If you have a primary key with lots of gaps, that helps to randomize.